# How to move beyond the limits of R in terms of memory

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory, r-caret

I am new to advanced R programming. Unfortunately, I am running into memory issues. On stack overflow I could only find somewhat older contributions. I could not find a solution that worked for me. Machine learning is rising in the last years so I think there are new solutions available. So, I am wondering what the best practices are nowadays. Is everyone working on a Azure server or are there other options that can be used locally?

(For completeness I will explain my context. But I think it is not relevant to the question itself... My context:
I perform my analysis on a linux server. The dataset is small enough to load into R without any problems. Details: 42mb, #rows: 225000, #columns: 25. However, when I want to run a random forest classification model and performing 5-fold cross-validation using the caret package. To improve computation time I'm running it over 8 clusters/cores. One of the errors I've got is "Error : cannot allocate vector of size ** GB")

Do you have suggestions for packages or information sources that I can try out? If you need more information to provide a suitable answer please let me know :)

Comment: "It's complicated."  See some intros to High-Performance Computing with R as _e.g._ the [CRAN Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) which has some pointers for out-of-memory packages and approaches.

Comment: But the old rules of thumb from decades ago still holds: "have 3x RAM for data of size x".  R (and S before it) want all data in memory _unless other algos or tricks are used_ and make temporary copies.  They also want contiguous memory for vectors and matrices so sometimes you "hit the wall" even if RAM remains (but in small chunks).

Comment: I am a bit suprised that you run out of memory with such a small dataset. You could check out `tidymodels` which is kind of the inofficial successor of caret and might be a bit more flexible and maybe less memory expensive. I often do fits on folds seperately and store intermediate results when I run out of memory. However, this can get awful very fast :P

Comment: You can try ``memory.limit(128000)``, it might work or might not. It definitively worked for some of my project where I was working with 100GB data and had the : ''Error : cannot allocate vector of size xxxxx...'' You can edit the number in the function to a bigger one (just be sure it's higher than your RAM total memory).

Comment: @Gainz i thought that is windows solution and im working on linux server so that wont work...

Comment: @HeiN3r I will try it out thanks :)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks! I found that page on monday. Great overview.  I thought the package 'ff' had the most potential but i get other errors. 
Like: Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection. 
And again a warning: Warning message: system call failed: Cannot allocate memory.
The interesting part is that with 20% of the data it works both with caret and caret+FF... So it must be to hard to handle al data at ones.

Comment: @slvg I'm sorry for some reasons I thought it was also available on Linux.